# Creating Pdf with data from editText android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a `pdf`. Data is directly taken from edit text but the problem is that if I write any paragraph in the edit text the final out in `pdf` is showing all data in 1 line instead of multi-line.
Although `pdf` is getting created and I can see the output only in 1 single line.
    Image links:

**Stating activity:**
[image]

**File created:**
[image]

**File viewed:**
[image]

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnCreate;
    EditText editText,editText2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        btnCreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
        editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        editText2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createPdf(editText.getText().toString(),editText2.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void createPdf(String title,String description){
        // create a new document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        // crate a page description

        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 600, 1).create();
        // start a page
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(title, 20, 40, paint);
        canvas.drawText(description, 20, 60, paint);
       // canvas.drawText(description,1,20,20.0f,30.0f,paint);
        //canvas.drawt
        // finish the page
        document.finishPage(page);
// draw text on the graphics object of the page

        // write the document content
        String directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mypdf/";
        File file = new File(directory_path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String targetPdf = directory_path+title+".pdf";
        File filePath = new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("main", "error "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(),  
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // close the document
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you have to find the EOF character and change the String to be written into the file accordingly.(using escape sequence)

Comment: not helpfull 
amy other wau

Comment: createPdf(editText.getText().toString()+"\n",editText2.getText().toString());

Comment: @Abr not working out

Comment: try the maxlines property inside xml, maybe

Comment: I suggest you to use Itext  https://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because `multiline` is property of `EditText`, not `String`, so if you read it from ET it will always be in single line. You can try to set max line length, and then read characters to limit, and then add it to new `String`, for example `ArrayList<String>` (you don't know how long text will be). If line limit doesn't end with `,` or `.` or `space`, then you read it further till `,` or `.` or `space` occurs. After all that you add whole ArrayList to your pdf, ending with `\n` each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string you get from the editText with some predefined Length and then using it in canvas.drawText()

```
while(description.length()>15){
    if(description.length()>15){
        String first = description.substring(0,15);
        canvas.drawText(description, 20, 60, paint);
    }
    else{
        String second =description.substring(0,description.length());
        canvas.drawText(description, 20, 60, paint);
    }

}
```

I have not tried this one. This might work